# How to fix Java SDK 1.8 installer "computing space requirements" forever?

Tags: windows-7, java, installer

When running Java SDK 1.8 installer on windows 7 it never stops "computing space requirements", how can I get around this ?

Answer (score 0):

After uninstalling "AVG free", the JDK installs successfully.